# Get conversion rate info for the data

Tags: mongodb

I have a lots of analytic data from users like:
app_opened, product_show, product_booked.

Is it possible by means of Mongo aggregation to get information like:

1. 100 users (100%) had app_opened event
2. 60 users (60% from previous step, 60% total) had product_show event
3. 10 users (20% of prev event, 10% total) had product_booked event

Considering that events happened within 10 minute window, without duplicating.

Comment: Yes it is possible. But without sample data and expected results from it, it will be hard to say more than this.